# できる人と思わせるために下準備が必要です

Tags: meaning

> できる人と思わせるために下準備が必要です。しかし、実は最大の下準備は、何といっても「自分を知る」ことである。

Just wanted to confirm the above meaning, does it mean this?

> To make people think that they can do it, preparations are necessary?
> BUT the most preparations are called "I know everything"

Comment: 「何といっても」 is an idiomatic phrase, meaning "After all".  https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E4%BD%95%E3%81%A8%E8%A8%80%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82/#je-56896

Comment: 「 **自分**を知る」がどうして "I know **everything**" になったんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

Let me break it down to smaller chunks:

> できる人と思わせるために下準備が必要です。

できる人 -- 有能な人, a competent person
～と思わせる -- make others think (of you) as...
ために -- in order to; so as to
下準備 -- preliminary arrangements/preparations
～が必要です。 -- ...are necessary.

*lit.* In order to make others think that you are a competent person, you need preliminary arrangements.

---

> しかし、実は最大の下準備は、何といっても「自分を知る」ことである。

しかし -- but
実は -- actually; in fact; as a matter of fact
最大の -- the biggest; the most crucial
下準備は(...である。) -- preliminary arrangement/preparation (is...)
何といっても -- after all; to say the least; no matter how you look at it
「自分を知る」こと -- to "know oneself"
である。 -- (copula)

*lit.* But, in fact, the most crucial preliminary arrangement is to "know yourself", after all.

Comment: What does 思わせる mean then, who is it directed and who is it coming from?

Comment: @fynxgloire 思わせる is causative, "make others think". Here it means 「自分ができる人だと人に思わせる」, "make others think that you are a できる人". 「できる人」 means 「有能な人」, "a competent person".